# iOS 8 gray box over UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios8

I am making an app where I need to use `UITableView`s to display content in an organized fashion, but since I updated to iOS 8 and Xcode 6 I have been getting a mystery gray box over almost the entire view. This can be seen in the image below. This does not happen on every `UITableView`, just some (with no apparent pattern).

[image]

Comment: Don't paste dead link.

Comment: fixed the link. hate my website provider.

Comment: As iOS 8 isn't publicly available yet you'll struggle to get an answer. Apple don't like you talking about their private APIs

Comment: Don't misunderstand what Matt says, you are very welcome to discuss any issues related to prerelease products at the Apple [Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/).

Comment: @A-Live: Thank you for putting that image in the post for me.  I don't have enough reputation (don't understand that, but oh well).

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same problem (the ridiculous huge gray rectangle). It shows up when I try to use tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier() to create a row from a prototype cell.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In `iOS 8`, you **must** specify a height in the `UITableView`'s delegate:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 44.0;
}
```

In `iOS 7` and earlier, a default was accepted.  See [this link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/991443#991443) for more information.

Comment: Good to know! I had tried manually specifying a row height in Interface Builder, but that didn't work. I guess it has to be done in code right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in XCode6-Beta2. I found a workaround. Select the storyboard, and go to the File Inspector utility. Uncheck the option "Use Auto Layout" then click "Disable Size Classes" in the popup.

Auto Layout seems to be quite broken in beta2. Once you turn off Size Classes, the mysterious "ambiguous scrollable content" warnings will also go away.

I was able to turn Size Classes and Auto Layout back on afterward and the gray rectangle is still gone, but everything is in the wrong place after losing the Size Classes info. It's a mess.

Comment: I do have the "Ambiguous scrollable content" errors and wondered about these as well.  As for the gray box, I turned off `Auto Layout` and the gray boxes disappeared; however, when I turned it back on the box came back (unlike in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, it has to do with the Table View Separator Style. If you set that to None, the problem will go away. But of course, then you have no separators! If you want to use Single Line separators, you have to manually specify a cell height in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I have no idea why this is the case, but I am guessing it has something to do with the new self-sizing table rows. Time to do some research :)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 the row height can be set automatically for you.
All you have to do is set a top and bottom constraint to the contentView of the UITableViewCell, like this (notice the constraints):

[image: Interface builder - defining the uitableviewcell]

By doing this, the row height will be automatic and you won't need to set a fixed height.
This fixes the gray background color you have encountered.

Resource: http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/07/24/ios8-day-by-day-day-5-auto-sizing-table-view-cells